# move_uploaded_file() failed with correct file path

Tags: php

I managed to get the `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` but it failed to upload temp file to folder. I've created a folder to store temp file same path as php file. Checked if the file exists with `is_dir('/var/www/html/uploads/user/test_uploads/')` return exists. Somehow this function is not working.

Here is the picture of the dir:

[image]

And below is my code:

```
<?php 
    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; // The file name
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder

    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "/var/www/html/uploads/user/test_uploads/$fileName")){
        echo "$fileName is uploaded successsfully.";
    } else {
        echo "Upload failed.";
    }
?>
```

Below is my HTML code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file_upload_parser.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
    Send this file: <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

Comment: check your folder permission

Comment: Check permissions and use `__DIR__` instead of hard-coding path (eg. when you'll want to transfer website to another webhosting, switching between localhost and remote server, etc). `var/www/...` is coding hell.

Comment: permission tick all for Allow?

Comment: i've changed permission and use __DIR__ but still not working,

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_FILES["file"]);`, and check what the `error` element contains.